# How can I know when my table got hit in sql server 2008 r2 express profiler when run from browser

Tags: sql-server-2008r2-express

I have one important table called **Person** among hundreds of tables. But, I'm not sure when it is coming into play. I have to capture table information in such a way that as soon as the **Person** table is queried by one particular page in the browser, it should prompt me quickly, so that I can record that particular page needs **Person** table.

Without knowing how to do this I can't make much progress. Can anybody please suggest to me how can I achieve this? Can we achieve this with SQL Server profiler? Or is there any other technique?

Comment: Your web browser doesn't query tables; the page on your web server queries the tables on the browser's behalf. It's really unclear to me what you're attempting to achieve here. Are you trying to figure out which portion of your database your web application accesses?

Comment: @alroc: Yes, I am trying to figure out which "TABLE" my web application accesses. I want this result as soon as the table has been accessed.

Comment: Then why aren't you looking at your application's source code? And why must it be "instant" notification? You should only need to use a profiler trace as you describe to reverse-engineer an application, and in that scenario Profiler is going to be streaming so much data back to you that "instant" notification when a table is accessed is going to be difficult - in that case you'd review the transcript after running your tests. Profiler doesn't (to my knowledge) emit "alerts". Other methods will likely result in a lot of additional load being placed on your server.

Comment: We (as a team) joined just some months before in this project. But, some other people are working on this SAME project since last more than 10 years. They also don't know what table is getting referred in which page. Don't take literal meaning of alert, I want some mechanism to let me know instantly. To express this, I have used the "alert" word. I also mentioned in my post that I AM LOOKING FOR SOLUTION NOT ONLY THROUGH SQL SERVER PROFILER; BUT ANY OTHER TOOL IF IT IS AVAILABLE.

Comment: The best tool to use is your application's source code. That is the definitive answer to "what is accessing which tables and when" and a far better use of the company's time than poring through thousands of events from a Profiler (or any other tool) trace.